# how to get selected value from radio button from html in angular Js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, radio-button

i try to get selected value from radio button 
But when i choose teacher it still be s "student"

Html File :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="phase2">

<head>
<title>Sign UP Page</title>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.2.28" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="RigesterationController.js"></script>
</head>
<body >

<center>

<p>Enter Your User Name : <input type="text" , name="UserName" id ="UName"  required /> </p>
<p>Enter Your Email : <input type="text" , name="Email" id ="email" required /> </p>
<p>Enter Your Password : <input type="password" , name="pass" id ="Pass" required/> </p>
<p>Choose Gender : <br> Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="m" id="Gender" checked/>    Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="f" id="Gender"/> </p>
<p>Choose User Type :<br>  Student<input type="radio" name="UserType" value="s" id="Utype"  checked/>     Teacher<input  type="radio" name="UserType" value="t" id="Utype"/> </p>

<div ng-app="phase2" >
 <div ng-controller="SignUP">
  <input type="button" name="signup" value="SignUP" ng-click="save()" />
 </div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

RigesterationController.js File :

```js
var app = angular.module("phase2" , [])
app.controller( "SignUP" ,function ($scope , $http , srvShareData , $location)
  {
   $scope.dataToShare = [];
   $scope.save = function() {
    var email= document.getElementById("email").value;
    var UName=document.getElementById("UName").value;
    var Pass=document.getElementById("Pass").value;
    var gender=document.getElementById("Gender").value;
    var UserType=document.getElementById("Utype").value;
    alert(UserType)
    $http.get('http://localhost:8090/SignUp/'+email+'/'+UName+'/'+Pass+'/'+gender+'/'+UserType)
    .then(function(response)
     {
     });
    if (UserType=="t")
    {
    window.location.href="http://localhost:8060/TheAngular_Project/TeacherPage.html";
    }
    else if (UserType=="s")
    {
    window.location.href="http://localhost:8060/TheAngular_Project/StudentPage.html";
    }
    }
  });
```

i get always s although I choose teacher .. how to get selected value ?
thanks in advance

Comment: document.getElementById("email").value ? use ng-model value instead

Comment: email and user name and password works successfully .. problem in radio buttons @Sajeetharan

Comment: @AhmedHassan I suggest you to read on angular first. You are doing the basics wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some suggestions :**

- **Why `ng-app="phase2"` two times ?**

  - The ng-app directive is used to auto-bootstrap an AngularJS application. And according to AngularJS Documentation, only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document.
- **Why `ng-controller` directive only on submit button as form fields(input elements) also the part of the form ?**

  - it should come on the parent element.
- **Why plain `Javascript` to get the form data as you can use `ng-model` or other angular `directives` to communicate between the controller and view ?**

  - You can pass form data using ng-model into the controller as it is very popular and powerful feature in AngularJS instead of doing in a wrong way.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('phase2',[]);

myApp.controller('SignUP', function($scope) {
    $scope.save = function(selectedUser) {
      alert(selectedUser);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="phase2" ng-controller="SignUP">
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="save(uType)">
<p>Choose User Type :<br>Student<input type="radio" name="UserType" value="s" ng-model="uType"/>Teacher<input type="radio" name="UserType" value="t" ng-model="uType"/></p>
<input type="submit" name="signup" value="SignUP"/>
</form>
</div>
```